# How can I minimize my code when I use a while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I had this assignment to creat a super market product list and I was trying to go throw the price elements which represent the products prices for product 1 to 10. I tried to do dictionary and use while loop but it didn't work. Any help on how to improve my code and make it more compact ?

```
print("""Supermarket
===========""")

prices = [10,14,22,33,44,13,22,55,66,77]
totalsum = []

while True:
        selection = int(input("Please select product (1-10) 0 to Quit:"))
        if selection == 0:
            print("Total: ", sum(totalsum))
            payment = int(input("Payment: "))
            var1 = payment - sum(totalsum)
            print("Change: ", var1)
            break
            
        elif selection == 1: 
            print("Product: ", selection, " Price:", prices[0])
            totalsum.append(prices[0])
            
        
        elif selection == 2: 
            print("Product: ", selection, " Price:", prices[1])
            totalsum.append(prices[1])
            
            
        elif selection == 3: 
            print("Product: ", selection, " Price:", prices[2])
            totalsum.append(prices[2])
            
        elif selection == 4: 
            print("Product: ", selection, " Price:", prices[3])
            totalsum.append(prices[3])
            
        elif selection == 5: 
            print("Product: ", selection, " Price:", prices[4])
            totalsum.append(prices[4])
            
        elif selection == 6: 
            print("Product: ", selection, " Price:", prices[5])
            totalsum.append(prices[5])
            
        elif selection == 7: 
            print("Product: ", selection, " Price:", prices[6])
            totalsum.append(prices[6])
            
        elif selection == 8: 
            print("Product: ", selection, " Price:", prices[7])
            totalsum.append(prices[7])
            
        elif selection == 9: 
            print("Product: ", selection, " Price:", prices[8])
            totalsum.append(prices[8])
            
        elif selection == 10: 
            print("Product: ", selection, " Price:", prices[9])
            totalsum.append(prices[9])
```

Comment: prices[selection-1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to check what the value of `selection`. You can simply index `prices` with selection as shown below.

```
print("""Supermarket
===========""")

prices = [10,14,22,33,44,13,22,55,66,77]
totalsum = []

while True:
        selection = int(input("Please select product (1-10) 0 to Quit:"))
        if selection == 0:
            print("Total: ", sum(totalsum))
            payment = int(input("Payment: "))
            var1 = payment - sum(totalsum)
            print("Change: ", var1)
            break
        print("Product: ", selection, " Price:", prices[selection-1])
        totalsum.append(prices[selection-1])
```

This obviously reduced the amount of lines drastically.